# Passing UnsafeMutablePointer to Ref Object in a function in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, cgpdf, unsafemutablepointer, cgpdfscanner

I'm developing a pdf parser in swift, so i've stumbled upon the function CGPDFScannerPopString which takes a CGPDFScannerRef and an UnsafeMutablePointer?

The Objective C code looks like this:

```
CGPDFStringRef pdfString;
CGPDFScannerPopString(pdfScanner, &pdfString);
```

How do I write this in swift 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the second parameter of `CGPDFScannerPopString` is `UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPDFStringRef?>?`. So, you need to prepare a variable of type `CGPDFStringRef?` and pass it as an inout argument:

```
var pdfString: CGPDFStringRef?
_ = CGPDFScannerPopString(pdfScanner, &pdfString)
```

Comment: that's what I tried at first, however there's a couple of errors showing up telling me that there's an extra argument in call and that an expression is expected in list of expressions...

Comment: @MichaelSchmid, the code above compiles without any problems in my Xcode 8.1. If you have found such errors, some other things may be affecting. You should show whole code which can reproduce your issue.

Comment: sorry I missed a parenthese... long day already   thanks for the help

Comment: That may happen. Take some rest (I hope you can...). Good luck.